# "which nvm" is gone

Tags: ubuntu, path, cron, nvm

I installed NVM on an ubuntu machine, but, when I put it in the crontab for execution during reboot:

```
@reboot nvm use 0;
```

it didn't work, and I got a mail from the cron daemon, saying:

```
/bin/sh: 1: nvm: not found
```

So, I thought this a path problem, and tried to find where NVM is installed. To my surprise, I got empty results:

```
root@vps-1145280-18735:~# which nvm
root@vps-1145280-18735:~#
```

But, NVM itself does work, even after reboot:

```
root@vps-1145280-18735:~# nvm

Node Version Manager
...
```

This is very strange - how can it be that the system finds the nvm program, when the "which nvm" is empty?!

And, more important - what should I do in order to have the cron program find NVM during startup?

Comment: Does this answer your question Erel?

Comment: Duplicate of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921427/nodejs-gone-after-linux-reboot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585261/nvm-keeps-forgetting-node-in-new-terminal-session

Answer (score 25):

The `nvm` command is not a file but rather a shell function.

The `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` adds these functions to your current shell. And because these commands are not files, they don't show up when you `which nvm`.

Looking in the `.nvm/nvm.sh` file, you can see a nvm() {...} function defined that provides that functionality.

Cron is likely using as different user, and that user needs to have `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` added to its shell context before running.