# nodejs gone after linux reboot

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I just installed nodejs version 0.10.14 using nvm it installed successfully. 
also before installing nodejs, I installed zeromq version 2.2.0.

For test purpose I was trying to run a basic pub example below.

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var socket = zmq.socket('pub');

console.log("Binding socket on port 8800...");

socket.bind('tcp://localhost:8800', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    } else{
        console.log("listening on port 8800");
    }
});
socket.send("hello this is testServer2 on port 8800...");
```

but it was throwing error -

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
TypeError: Socket is busy
    at Socket._ioevents (/home/zishan/node_modules/zmq/lib/index.js:198:22)
    at Socket._flush (/home/zishan/node_modules/zmq/lib/index.js:343:23)
    at Socket.send (/home/zishan/node_modules/zmq/lib/index.js:318:42)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/zishan/newsURLCollector/testServer2.js:16:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

port 8800 is already opened using ufw.

I tried googling the socket busy error but with no luck, than I thought it's good to reboot Ubuntu and the problem goes even worse. when I log back in and tries to run the above example again, system throws the message:

```
zishan@news01:~/newsURLCollector$ node testServer2.js

The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

WHY on earth a working node stops working and is unable to find node. then I followed the system prompt and did **sudo apt-get install node** below is the result:

```
zishan@news01:~$ sudo apt-get install node
[sudo] password for zishan:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libpgm-5.1-0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed
  node
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,284 B of archives.
After this operation, 38.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package node.
(Reading database ... 66172 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking node (from .../node_0.3.2-7.4_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up node (0.3.2-7.4) ...
zishan@news01:~$ node -v
```

then i tried to find the node version but nothing is happening, I am not getting a node prompt now but when i did "which node" it says - /usr/sbin/node

I do not know what is wrong after the reboot. Could any one please explain.

Answer (score 10):

When NVM loads, it loads whatever version of Node is currently marked as `default`.

`nvm install v0.10.14` will install `v0.10.14` and tell NVM to make it available for you to use by typing `node` in your current terminal, but it does not mark it as default, since you could just as easily have installed 5 versions of node. NVM also does not do anything fancy like remember what version of Node you were using last, since maybe you have 10 terminals open with a different version in each one.

All you need to do was run `nvm use v0.10.14` to tell your given terminal to expose `v0.10.14` as `node`.

In your case, the best thing to do would probably be to set it as the default, so it will use it on every restart and new terminal:

```
nvm alias default v0.10.14
```

As you figured out already, by running

```
apt-get install node
```

you installed this: http://packages.qa.debian.org/n/node.html

I would recommend you also now `apt-get remove nodejs` and stick with `nvm`. The `deb` packages get out-of-date fairly rapidly and using NVM will allow you to keep up much more easily.

Comment: thanks logan, i was unaware of the nvm's default working. (or I just ignored it). well doing apt-get installed the 0.10.24 which is recent. but yes, i will use nvm in future installs.

Comment: Remove `v` from `nvm alias default v0.10.14`, type `nvm` to see examples.

Comment: @NabilKadimi I'm not sure I follow. You can do either one and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After long struggle it is working now, I used below link to remove and then install node again using apt-get. but the only thing new I used now is removing node using purge switch.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/235655/node-js-conflicts-sbin-node-vs-usr-bin-node

below i used from above link:

sudo apt-get --purge remove node
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs

Now nodejs is working fine and zmq as well. I think it's the purge command which does the job as previously I was building from the source tar and removing manually as apt-get alone was not working!

Note for others - not all version of nodejs is compatible with zmq, one which I am using is
Nodejs - 0.10.24
zeromq - 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Basically the package installed on your machine was called 'nodejs' instead of 'node'. So your command needed to be changed to:

`zishan@news01:~/newsURLCollector$ nodejs testServer2.js`

the package 'node' in ubuntu has already been taken by Amateur Packet Radio "Node" Program, so when node came along to ubuntu apt packages, it was renamed to nodejs.